# how to get the text of parent node if i drag drop child node?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using tree, The structure of the tree is as per the attached image.

[image: Doubt]

Exactly what i am trying to do is the while i dragging and dropping child element which is dragged item in picture.
I want to get the text of parent li as shown in the figure but i am not getting it.

Right now i am trying with this way below is my code:

```
libName=$(ui.draggable).prevAll("li.lib:first").text();
```

where lib is class name of parent li but i am not getting any text. so how to get it.

Comment: You need to use [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Answer (score 2):

[`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents) combined with [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first) will help you find the parent `li`:

```
libName=$(ui.draggable).parents("li").first().text();
```

Alternately, [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) may be a bit more efficient (as it doesn't have to visit all ancestors; not that it likely matters), but you have to use [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) first because the dragged item will match otherwise:

```
libName=$(ui.draggable).parent().closest("li").text();
```

Note that we can use `first` on the result of `parents` because the set is ordered according to the parent closest to the element (then the next ancestor, etc.).

---

You've commented below:

> But it is listing me parent and sibling li too...But i need only parent li

If you mean you want the text of the parent item **without** the text of the list it contains (that is, only the text it **directly** contains), you can use `contents` for that instead of `text` (probably using `$.trim` as well, to remove leading and trailing whitespace):

```
libName=$.trim($(ui.draggable).parent().closest("li").contents().map(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 ? this.nodeValue : ""; // 3 == text node
}).get().join(""));
```

Comment: Thanks @T.j. Crowder. But it is listing me parent and sibling li too

Comment: But i need only parent li.

Comment: @Mayur: Do you mean you want the text of the parent item **without** the text of the list it contains?

Comment: Its not getting the value its just printing blank

Comment: @Mayur: Assuming `ui.draggable` is the element you've indicated, the above works: http://jsbin.com/kilibe/1

Comment: Yes this way i want. but what should i give to nodeType as tree is dynamic.

Comment: @Mayur: `nodeType === 3` checks to see if the node is a text node (as opposed to an element). It's a type, not an index. You shouldn't have to change it.